# char *foo vs char* foo

Tags: c++, c, coding-style

**Simple question is:** why do you write

```cpp
char *foo;
```

and not

```cpp
char* foo;
```

**Let me explain:** for me (coming from Java) a declaration is something like

```
<variable-type> <variable-name>;
```

In the above case I declare a variable named `foo` of type `char*` (as it is a pointer pointing to char). But wherever I read c/c++/c#-Code it looks like a variable named `*foo` of type `char`. The compiler does not care about whitespaces but I as a developer do.

**tl;dr** What I ask for is a good explanation for writing `char *foo` instead of `char* foo` (what, as explained, seems more convenient for me).

Comment: Please be specific about what language you are asking about. C# doesn't normally use pointers, so not sure why you included it.

Comment: You left out the most common form `char * foo`.

Comment: Please see [Stroustrup's FAQ](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#whitespace).

Comment: dtb already edited the c# away, it was mainly to show that it is no (real) language-specific problem that I have. (c# does _allow_ pointers but you don't normally _use_ them, you're right)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Think of the following declaration:

```
char *p, c;
```

This declares a pointer to char called `p` and a character variable called `c`. This shows that it isn't exactly correct to think of variable declaration as having the simple and clear format you described.

Comment: So for the lazy case to declare two variables in the same line you use it everywhere that way (even if it seems not to be the best way - for me - to do it)?

Comment: No, it's because that's the way the language works. The language doesn't treat a `*` as logically part of the type but more of as a type modifier that binds to the specific variable declared, not the declaration. In the line in the answer, only `p` is "modified" to be a pointer. That's how the language works.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz More precisely the * is part of the declarator (8.0.0), and expands the fundamental type to a compound type.

Answer (score 5):

Just to be clear, in C and C++, *both are perfectly legal*, and there is no single agreed-upon "best way to do it".

The reason for writing `char *foo` is code like this:

```
char* foo, bar;
```

this does not, as you would expect on casually reading the code, declare two char pointers.
It declares a char pointer (foo), and a char (bar).

If you want to declare two char pointers, you need this:

```
char* foo, * bar;
```

and that just looks odd, so a more consistent version is this:

```
const *foo, *bar;
```

this is the only way to make it clear that the `*` is really a qualifier on that specific variable, rather than being bound to the type.

But many, myself included, prefer the same as you, and always write `char* foo`
Then I just have to avoid declaring two variables in a single statement like above.
Overall, that's not hard. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I always go for the `char* var` way. Exactly because of your rational. 
I guess its a matter of habit.

Answer (score 1):

A declaration of a variable splits in three parts: The base type, the declarators and the name. If you separate this with commas, here is what you get:

```
char *a, b, c[5], *d[5];
```

Were a's type is "pointer to char", b's "char", c's "array of 5 char" and d's "array of 5 pointer to char". This is the reason why in C and C++ it would be more logical to write the star to the name, as it doesn't belong to the base type.

However, it belongs to the type and (type) (name) is easier to understand for people, that is why you see char* very often. In my opinion both ways are perfectly fine, as long as you declare only one variable in each line when going with char*. (This is what many coding standards require anyway.)